How to Monitor CDC Jobs
Is there a way to monitor CDC jobs similar to Monitor -> Jobs --> Apex jobs?
Monitor -> Jobs --> Apex Jobs will show all batch and Queueable jobs but it does not show the CDC jobs

Salesforce does allow you to track the usage of Change Data capture events.
A sample query from Salesforce doc:-
SELECT EventName, EventType, UsageType, Value, StartDate, EndDate 
FROM PlatformEventUsageMetric 
WHERE TimeSegment='Hourly'

The sample result would be in this format:-

you can further filter out for change_event.
